# How to do per record field something?

Tags: generics, haskell

Is it possible to work on the fields of a Haskell record type?

Something like `getPosition :: RecordField -> Int` would probably be enough for my purpose. Something that let's me index based on the name of a record field in a type safe manner.

My guess is that this is doable by resorting to template haskell but currently my code is highly `GHC.Generics` centric. Is there a solution for this using Generics?

### Edit 4: The real thing

Ok ... I guess I should just include the whole thing:

http://pastebin.com/kaZjTBnH

So my goal is to write a generic `KDTree`. Currently inserting and deleting is working fine, but I want to do `query filters` based on conditions on the fields above it:

```
query :: Query -> KDTree a -> KDTree a

data Foo = Foo {fooA :: Int, fooB :: Int} deriving (Show,Generic)

data FooQuery = FooAQuery Ordering Int
              | FooBQuery Ordering Int


result1 = query (FooAQuery LT 10) barTree
result2 = query (FooAQuery LT 10 <> FooBQuery EQ 0) barTree
```

This is of course highly speculative syntax.
I guess it is possible to create something like this via Template Haskell ... but I hope there is another way to achieve this.

---

[1] In the end this won't be a `Vec Ordering` but will be 'optimized' into a single `Int` where each bit denotes wether the corresponding field is LTEQ or GT.

Comment: The very idea doesn't sound exactly type-safe.

Comment: No ... Not from the programmers perspective. But I hope to do a type safe API for the resulting library.

Comment: Maybe if you explain your goal more, someone will propose a better solution.

Comment: @Florian Where is that Vec type from? Is it "Vector" from the vector package or is it a "Vector" encoded with the Vec package?

Comment: Oh ... It's `Vector` from the vector package.

Comment: @Florian would something like [this](http://ideone.com/fqQglv) work?

Comment: @bennofs Not sure I get all of that, but it looks like you compare the two fields 'direct' which is not quite what I need. I guess I should add my 'real' code ... above.

Comment: @Florian I convert your Vec Ordering back into a Foo that contains a Ordering on each field. Then I compare the orderings of the given field.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33018/discussion-between-florian-and-bennofs)